# Removing the zoom when double-clicking in amCharts?

Tags: javascript, html, amcharts

I am using amCharts - map chart.

How do I remove the zoom when double-clicking and the home icon on the map in amCharts?

**HTML:**

```
<head>
  <title>jVectorMap demo</title>
  <script src="ammap/ammap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="ammap/ammap.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
  <script src="ammap/maps/js/japanHigh.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/map.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="mapdiv" style="width: 1350px; height: 550px;"></div>
</body>
```

**Javascript:**

```
let map = AmCharts.makeChart("mapdiv", {
  "type": "map",
  "dragMap": false,
  /* can't drag the maparound now*/

  "dataProvider": {
    "map": "japanHigh",
    "getAreasFromMap": true
  },

  "areasSettings": {
    // "autoZoom": false,
    "selectedColor": "#CC0000"
  },

  "zoomControl": {
    "zoomControlEnabled": false,
    /*removing the zoomin and out button from top left corner */
    // "maxZoomLevel": 0
    // "zoomFactor":false
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you provide your code and raise the specific problem?

Comment: i edited the que with codes sry im new to stackoverflow :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove zooming effect when ammap is double clicked, you can define `zoomOnDoubleClick` as `false`. To remove home icon, you can define `homeButtonEnabled` as `false`.

For your code, it would be:

```
let map = AmCharts.makeChart( "mapdiv", {
  "type": "map",
  "dragMap": false,     /* can't drag the maparound now*/
  "zoomOnDoubleClick": false,

  "dataProvider": {
    "map": "japanHigh",
    "getAreasFromMap": true
  },

  "areasSettings": {
    // "autoZoom": false,
    "selectedColor": "#CC0000"
  },

  "zoomControl": {
    "zoomControlEnabled": false,      /*removing the zoomin and out button from top left corner */
    "homeButtonEnabled": false
    // "maxZoomLevel": 0
    // "zoomFactor":false
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but when i doubleclick the map ,yes it doesn't zoom in but it moves around as if i'm dragging it. Do i need to adjust the width and height?

Comment: When you double click the map, the map will move around and center the double clicked point. You don't want this effect?

Comment: Nope, i just want it to be a still image where i can hover to see the districts name pop up.
p.s: if i keep double clicking the map keeps moving further and further, i don't want this to happen :D

Comment: I even tried adding listeners for clicks but couldn't make it work or maybe i used it incorrectly
  ` "listeners": [{
      "event": "zoomed",
      "method": handleZoom
   }]`

Comment: @dotthreethree Please check my edited answer, the "move around" effect after double click has been removed.

Comment: Thanks a lot brother, really appreciate the help :D
edit: were these in the docs? how did you comeup with these? if i may ask

Comment: Oh ok , i guess i didn't watch them closely.

Comment: Not your fault, I think the doc is a bit messy. It is better if amcharts can provide a doc with more clear structure.

Comment: o ya my prob was solved thanks, didn't know(newtostackoverflow) about the "accept" thing sorry haha. That tick mark is the accept, right?